# Local minimum of functions

Tags: derivatives

For $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f_c : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given as $f_c(x) = x^2(\phi(x) + c)$ where $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$ and $\phi(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \neq 0$. I have to prove that if $c \ge 1$ then $f_c$ has a local minimum in $0$ but for $r > 0$ function $f_c$ on domain $[0;r]$, $[-r; 0]$ is not monotonic. For what $c$ local minimum in $0$ is strict? Is $f_c$ differentiable?
$f_c'(x) = x(2(c+\phi(x))+x\phi'(x))$. Of course $f_c'(0) = 0$ and $2(c+\phi(x))$ is positive for $c \ge 1$. Can you help me what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when $c \geq 1$, $x^2(\phi(x)+c) \geq 0$ and at $x=0$ we have equality. For all other $c$, you would always be able to find a value as close to $0$ as you like, such that the function $f_c$ is smaller than zero. Only for $c \geq 1$ can it be a local minimum.

On the question whether it is differentiable, try to work with limits. The derivative is defined as $$ f'_c(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_c(x) - f_c(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin(1/x) + xc $$

Since $|x \sin(1/x)| \leq x$, the limit goes to $0$. This shows $f_c'(0)=0$. The derivative is clearly defined at any other point as well, showing that the function is in fact differentiable.